# Highlight which of the file names in emacs buffer are missing

Tags: emacs, overlay, elisp, highlighting

In GNU Emacs, I could use something like a hypothetical "flyexist.el" - I have a buffer with absolute (Unix) file names in it (plus some additional text around them). Most of those files exist, but some are missing. I would like to run a function that highlights me the missing files (maybe with a red overlay). This function would need to figure out which of the text in the buffer looks like a file name (some false positives are okay) and then work on it with file-exists-p.

For example, assume that my buffer contains

```
Some random text mentioning /file/that/does/exist.txt, 
some more random text, and a /file/that/does/not-exist.txt
```

I want to have the second file highlighted.

Does something like this exist already?

Comment: And you need the code to figure out that `/file/that/does/exist.txt` exists, even though `/file/that/does/exist.txt,` (presuambly) doesn't? Yet also not highlight `/file/that/does/not-exist.tx` if that one existed?

Comment: Well, if a file exists, it shouldn't be highlighted (or in a different color, e.g. green), but I want to quickly see files that are not existing.

Comment: @cmarqu: +1...  I'd find that very convenient as well.  Something resolving both */path/to/file* and *~/path/to/file* and highlighting missing files in red would be very useful : )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am new to emacs hacking... Here is my "minor-mode" version.

```
(defvar filehi-path-re "\\([/$][[:alnum:]$-_.]+\\)+"
  "Regexp used for path matching.")


(defface filehi-file-existing
  '((t (:foreground "White" :background "Green")))
  "Face for existing files.")

(defface filehi-file-missing
  '((t (:foreground "Yellow" :background "Red")))
  "Face for missing files.")

(defun filehi-check-and-highlight (start end)
  "Check if substring is existing file path and highlight it."
    (remove-overlays start end 'name 'filehi-highlight)
    (let ((overlay (make-overlay start end)))
      (overlay-put overlay 'name 'filehi-highlight)
      (overlay-put overlay 'face (if (file-exists-p (substitute-in-file-name
                                                     (buffer-substring start end)))
                                     'filehi-file-existing
                                   'filehi-file-missing))))


(defun filehi-highlight-file-paths (&optional start end _ignore)
   "Run through the buffer and highliht file paths."
    (save-excursion
      (save-match-data ; fixes problem with dabbrev (and may be more...)
        (remove-overlays (point-min) end 'name 'filehi-highlight)
        (let ((prev-end (point-min)))
          (goto-char (point-min)) ; FIXME use something like greedy
                                        ; search-backward
          (while (and (<= (point) end)
                      (re-search-forward filehi-path-re nil t))
            (filehi-check-and-highlight (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0)))))))


(define-minor-mode filehi-mode
  "Minor mode for highlighting existing file paths.
May conflict with other modes..."
  nil " Filehi" nil
  (if filehi-mode
      (progn ; enable mode
        (make-local-hook 'after-change-functions)
        (filehi-highlight-file-paths (point-min) (point-max))
        (add-hook 'after-change-functions 'filehi-highlight-file-paths nil t))
    ; disable mode
    (remove-hook 'after-change-functions 'filehi-highlight-file-paths t)
    (remove-overlays (point-min) (point-max) 'name 'filehi-highlight)))
```

Comment: Thanks, that is awesome. Since your solution was immediately useful and the most complete, I'm "Accept"ing it as the answer. Are you considering hosting that code in e.g. github, with proper licensing etc.?

Comment: Expanding environment variables is easy - just added one function call (see diff) and changed regexp. Elisp reference is your friend! As for hosting and licensing, you are free to do with this code anything you want. I don't want to maintain it :)

Comment: I have since amended the regexp a bit so that it also supports local file names - it expects to find at least a slash (/).
`(defvar filehi-path-re "\\([[:alnum:]$_.-]+/[[:alnum:]$_.\\*/-]+\\)"
  "Regexp used for path matching.")`

Answer (score 2):

Try with this (you have to trigger it manually though, or incorporate it into some other periodical routine):

```
(defun x-mark-missing-files ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
   (while (search-forward-regexp "~?/[A-Za-z./-]+")
     (when (not (file-exists-p (match-string 0)))
       (overlay-put
        (make-overlay (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
        'face '(:background "red"))))))
```

Play a little with the filename regexp to get it right how you want it.

Comment: Thank you too, I added 0-9 and _ to the regexp and it worked fine as well.